# Can we get the "Assigned To" and "Assigned By" data in Salesforce in postman?

Tags: salesforce, postman, crm, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

I want to get the details of **Task** who assigned the task and whom it is assigned in salesforce. I am using below link to get the details:

*{{_endpoint}}/services/data/v{{version}}/sobjects/<SOBJECT_API_NAME>/listviews/<LIST_VIEW_ID>/results*

The result is as below:

```
{
"developerName": "OpenTasks",
"done": true,
"id": "00B5Y00000EEqHZ",
"label": "Open Tasks",
"records": [
    {
        "columns": [
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "Subject",
                "value": "Reach out to Ms. Pac Man"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "Who.Name",
                "value": "Pac Man"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "What.Name",
                "value": "Power Pellets Inc"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "ActivityDate",
                "value": "Wed Mar 10 00:00:00 GMT 2021"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "Status",
                "value": "Not Started"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "Priority",
                "value": "Normal"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "Owner.NameOrAlias",
                "value": "KBhat"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "LastModifiedDate",
                "value": "Mon Apr 05 20:08:41 GMT 2021"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "LastModifiedBy.Alias",
                "value": "SGotad"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "Id",
                "value": "00T5Y00007SU8NgUAL"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "CreatedDate",
                "value": "Tue Mar 09 15:16:21 GMT 2021"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "SystemModstamp",
                "value": "Mon Apr 05 20:08:41 GMT 2021"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "Who.Id",
                "value": "0035Y00003nbrjSQAQ"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "WhoId",
                "value": "0035Y00003nbrjSQAQ"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "What.Id",
                "value": "0015Y00002bgNPeQAM"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "WhatId",
                "value": "0015Y00002bgNPeQAM"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "Owner.Id",
                "value": "0055Y00000DgOLoQAN"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "OwnerId",
                "value": "0055Y00000DgOLoQAN"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "LastModifiedBy.Id",
                "value": "0055Y00000DgOLoQAN"
            },
            {
                "fieldNameOrPath": "LastModifiedById",
                "value": "0055Y00000DgOLoQAN"
            }
        ]
    }
}],
"size":1
```

}

I am confused which is "Assigned By", which is "Assigned To" and "Completed By" or the URL is different to get these details?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_task.htm says OwnerId = Assigned To.

I don't recall seeing "Assigned By", "Completed By". They might be custom fields in your Salesforce or standard fields like "Last Modified By" that were renamed.

Use tool like [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/describe.php) to "describe" Task (uses SOAP API I think) Or in Utilities -> REST Explorer you should be able to fire `/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Task/describe` and see if it brings anything meaningful in "fields" node.